# Create dynamic object from string, with variables as anchor property values

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

In a function property of an element with `id: window`, I create dynamic objects as follows:

```
Qt.createQmlObject(
    'import QtQuick 2.3; Rectangle {color: "#00FF00"; width: 1; anchors.right: '+i+'; height:1; anchors.bottom: '+i+'; }',
    window, "dynamicPixels");
```

where `i` is the iterating variable of a loop containing this snippet.

When I attempt to do some calculation with `i`, and use that as the value in the dynamic object, it complains:

> Unexpected token: 'numeric literal'

I tried `Math.round()` thinking it might somehow have become double (even though the calculation involved only `int`s), but without change.

However, when I reduced the line to just `i` to make my post here clearer, I get the different error:

> Invalid property assignment: unsupported type "QQuickAnchorLine"

So do I have deeper problems - can I not use anchors at all in a dynamic object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [anchors.rightMargin](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#anchors.rightMargin-prop). `anchors.right` is for anchoring to items by ID.